# ACL ROLE_ADMIN does not work

Tags: php, security, symfony, acl

Maybe somebody here can help me.
I'm adding blog comments and add the rights on it.

- The rights for the user who created the blog the rights are OK.
- The rights for not logged user can view de comment so thats OK.
- The Admin can not edit/delete the comment... But whats wrong?

Part of the Controller code:

```
// Creating the ACL
$aclProvider = $this->get('security.acl.provider');
$objectIdentity = ObjectIdentity::fromDomainObject($blogComment);
$acl = $aclProvider->createAcl($objectIdentity);

// Creating full access for the admin
$roleSecurityIdentity = new RoleSecurityIdentity('ROLE_ADMIN');
$acl->insertObjectAce($roleSecurityIdentity, MaskBuilder::MASK_MASTER );

// Creating view rights for the not-logged in users
$roleSecurityIdentity = new RoleSecurityIdentity('IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY');
$acl->insertObjectAce($roleSecurityIdentity, MaskBuilder::MASK_VIEW );

// retrieving the security identity of the currently logged-in user
$securityContext = $this->get('security.context');
$user = $securityContext->getToken()->getUser();
$securityIdentity = UserSecurityIdentity::fromAccount($user);

// grant owner access
$acl->insertObjectAce($securityIdentity, MaskBuilder::MASK_OWNER);
$aclProvider->updateAcl($acl);
```

Symfony profiler Security

```
Username    Mitchel
Authenticated?  yes
Roles   [ROLE_ADMIN]
```

Database Dump:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 3.5.2.2
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Machine: localhost
-- Genereertijd: 17 sep 2012 om 14:19
-- Serverversie: 5.1.65
-- PHP-versie: 5.3.16

SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Tabelstructuur voor tabel `acl_classes`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `acl_classes` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `class_type` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNIQ_69DD750638A36066` (`class_type`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

--
-- Gegevens worden uitgevoerd voor tabel `acl_classes`
--

INSERT INTO `acl_classes` (`id`, `class_type`) VALUES
(1, 'MV\\BetaalbaarkozijnBundle\\Entity\\BlogComment');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Tabelstructuur voor tabel `acl_entries`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `acl_entries` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `class_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `object_identity_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `security_identity_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `field_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ace_order` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `mask` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `granting` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `granting_strategy` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `audit_success` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `audit_failure` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNIQ_46C8B806EA000B103D9AB4A64DEF17BCE4289BF4` (`class_id`,`object_identity_id`,`field_name`,`ace_order`),
  KEY `IDX_46C8B806EA000B103D9AB4A6DF9183C9` (`class_id`,`object_identity_id`,`security_identity_id`),
  KEY `IDX_46C8B806EA000B10` (`class_id`),
  KEY `IDX_46C8B8063D9AB4A6` (`object_identity_id`),
  KEY `IDX_46C8B806DF9183C9` (`security_identity_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

--
-- Gegevens worden uitgevoerd voor tabel `acl_entries`
--

INSERT INTO `acl_entries` (`id`, `class_id`, `object_identity_id`, `security_identity_id`, `field_name`, `ace_order`, `mask`, `granting`, `granting_strategy`, `audit_success`, `audit_failure`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, 1, NULL, 0, 128, 1, 'all', 0, 0),
(2, 1, 1, 2, NULL, 1, 1, 1, 'all', 0, 0),
(3, 1, 1, 3, NULL, 2, 64, 1, 'all', 0, 0);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Tabelstructuur voor tabel `acl_object_identities`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `acl_object_identities` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_object_identity_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `class_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `object_identifier` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `entries_inheriting` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNIQ_9407E5494B12AD6EA000B10` (`object_identifier`,`class_id`),
  KEY `IDX_9407E54977FA751A` (`parent_object_identity_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

--
-- Gegevens worden uitgevoerd voor tabel `acl_object_identities`
--

INSERT INTO `acl_object_identities` (`id`, `parent_object_identity_id`, `class_id`, `object_identifier`, `entries_inheriting`) VALUES
(1, NULL, 1, '1', 1);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Tabelstructuur voor tabel `acl_object_identity_ancestors`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `acl_object_identity_ancestors` (
  `object_identity_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `ancestor_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`object_identity_id`,`ancestor_id`),
  KEY `IDX_825DE2993D9AB4A6` (`object_identity_id`),
  KEY `IDX_825DE299C671CEA1` (`ancestor_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Gegevens worden uitgevoerd voor tabel `acl_object_identity_ancestors`
--

INSERT INTO `acl_object_identity_ancestors` (`object_identity_id`, `ancestor_id`) VALUES
(1, 1);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Tabelstructuur voor tabel `acl_security_identities`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `acl_security_identities` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `identifier` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `username` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNIQ_8835EE78772E836AF85E0677` (`identifier`,`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

--
-- Gegevens worden uitgevoerd voor tabel `acl_security_identities`
--

INSERT INTO `acl_security_identities` (`id`, `identifier`, `username`) VALUES
(2, 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY', 0),
(1, 'MV\\BetaalbaarkozijnBundle\\Entity\\User-User', 1),
(3, 'ROLE_ADMIN', 0);

--
-- Beperkingen voor gedumpte tabellen
--

--
-- Beperkingen voor tabel `acl_entries`
--
ALTER TABLE `acl_entries`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_46C8B8063D9AB4A6` FOREIGN KEY (`object_identity_id`) REFERENCES `acl_object_identities` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_46C8B806DF9183C9` FOREIGN KEY (`security_identity_id`) REFERENCES `acl_security_identities` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_46C8B806EA000B10` FOREIGN KEY (`class_id`) REFERENCES `acl_classes` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

--
-- Beperkingen voor tabel `acl_object_identities`
--
ALTER TABLE `acl_object_identities`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_9407E54977FA751A` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_object_identity_id`) REFERENCES `acl_object_identities` (`id`);

--
-- Beperkingen voor tabel `acl_object_identity_ancestors`
--
ALTER TABLE `acl_object_identity_ancestors`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_825DE2993D9AB4A6` FOREIGN KEY (`object_identity_id`) REFERENCES `acl_object_identities` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_825DE299C671CEA1` FOREIGN KEY (`ancestor_id`) REFERENCES `acl_object_identities` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

I also created a topic on [symfony](http://forum.symfony-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=46874) forum, but it seems that they are not so active as stackoverflow ;)

Symfony version: 2.1.2

Thnx,
Regards Mitchel

Comment: Hello, and welcome! You might also try looking over on [security](http://security.stackexchange.com/) as well, to see if this question might get more response over there.

Comment: No matching results for "symfony acl"

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to assign Roles by users

```
# Object
$idObjeto = ObjectIdentity::fromDomainObject($blogComment);

# User
$idUsuario = UserSecurityIdentity::fromAccount($usuario);

try {
    $acl = $this->get('security.acl.provider')->findAcl($idObjeto);
} catch (\Symfony\Component\Security\Acl\Exception\AclNotFoundException $e) {
    $acl = $this->get('security.acl.provider')->createAcl($idObjeto);
}

$acl->insertObjectAce($idUsuario, MaskBuilder::MASK_OPERATOR);
$this->get('security.acl.provider')->updateAcl($acl);
```